# renderModule is not a function : angular12 @nguniversal on prerender only

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-universal

Currently migrating a **static angular 8 website** to **angular 12**, **prerendering** pages fails locally.

First step was using `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` to generate latest scaffolding, then clean the previous angular8/universal code.

✅ I can successfully run `dev:ssr`, `build:ssr`, and `serve:ssr`.

```
"dev:ssr": "ng run website:serve-ssr",
"build:ssr": "ng build && ng run website:server",
"serve:ssr": "node dist/server/main.js",
```

❌ When running `npm run prerender` I have the following error

```
> ng run website_en:prerender

✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Copying assets complete.
✔ Index html generation complete.
Build at: 2021-08-02T13:56:58.216Z - Hash: b2a4bcc276d1ce7a8de9 - Time: 26662ms

✔ Server application bundle generation complete.
Build at: 2021-08-02T13:57:00.109Z - Hash: 0f46572a7951c62abea9 - Time: 31768ms

✖ Prerendering routes to ~/website/dist/en failed.
renderModule is not a function
```

I suspect some conflicts with previous code from angular8, but looking online most code sample looks similar to my project. Also project is very minimalist and without too many dependancies to conflict or struggle with.

### Full logs

```
$ npm run prerender

> website@0.0.0 prerender ~/website
> ng run website_en:prerender

Warning: Support was requested for IE 11 in the project's browserslist configuration. IE 11 support is deprecated since Angular v12.
For more information, see https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Copying assets complete.
✔ Index html generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files                   | Names         |      Size
main.2703b1ee464983914c90.js          | main          | 549.78 kB
polyfills-es5.2669892dbe0306fd6806.js | polyfills-es5 | 196.24 kB
polyfills.09b63a2959800df8a004.js     | polyfills     | 103.74 kB
styles.ee78a15edec5586952fa.css       | styles        |  51.58 kB
runtime.0ad0b9f7bc4456da9d9e.js       | runtime       |   3.41 kB

                                      | Initial Total | 904.75 kB

Lazy Chunk Files                      | Names         |      Size
459.ca33d2d2dfd51ae7e99b.js           | -             |  12.67 kB
341.48060e5c202342d1cc32.js           | -             |  12.41 kB
34.4553ce01726f9dd74f9c.js            | -             |   9.67 kB
846.d0bde86d8ef5c235cb29.js           | -             |   6.73 kB
284.f7119b6b03003373bf17.js           | -             |   5.25 kB
common.a1228fa90f251ccea342.js        | common        | 922 bytes

Build at: 2021-08-02T13:56:58.216Z - Hash: b2a4bcc276d1ce7a8de9 - Time: 26662ms
✔ Server application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files | Names         |    Size
main.js             | main          | 4.50 MB

                    | Initial Total | 4.50 MB

Build at: 2021-08-02T13:57:00.109Z - Hash: 0f46572a7951c62abea9 - Time: 31768ms
✖ Prerendering routes to ~/website/dist/en failed.
renderModule is not a function
```

### angular.json

I believe my `angular.json` is properly configured

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "website_en": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/en",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "development": {},
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": {
                  "minify": true,
                  "inlineCritical": false
                },
                "fonts": true
              },
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "website_en:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "website_en:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "website_en:build:development"
            }

          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "website_en:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {},
            "development": {}
          }
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "website_en:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "website_en:server:development"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "website_en:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "website_en:server:production"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "website_en:build:production",
            "serverTarget": "website_en:server:production",
            "routesFile": "./static.paths.txt"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {}
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "website_en",
  "cli": {
    "warnings": {
      "typescriptMismatch": false
    }
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "css"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

### static.paths.txt

My file `static.paths.txt` seams to be properly loaded as npm briefly report generating 4 urls before to trigger the error

```
/contact
/resources
/legal
```

### tsconfig.json

Not much to expect I guess from tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
  "include": [
    "server.ts"
  ]
}
```

### tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": []
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "main.server.ts",
    "app/app.server.ts"
  ]
}
```

### tsconfig.server.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    // Set the module format to "commonjs":
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  // Add "angularCompilerOptions" with the AppServerModule you wrote
  // set as the "entryModule".
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/app.server#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

### server.ts

Only issue I had was regarding generated server.ts when importing express. My tsconfig was complaining and I could fix easily but using `import express from "express";`. Once again, dynamic ssr works as expected.

```
Error: server.ts:13:18 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof e' has no call signatures.

13   const server = express();
                    ~~~~~~~

  server.ts:4:1
    4 import * as express from "express";
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Type originates at this import. A namespace-style import cannot be called or constructed, and will cause a failure at runtime. Consider using a default import or import require here instead.
```

### versions

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "^12.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "^12.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.1.4",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^12.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "^12.1.4",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^12.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@sentry/browser": "^6.10.0",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "core-js": "^3.16.0",
    "country-flag-emoji": "^1.0.3",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "express-sslify": "^1.2.0",
    "geo-tz": "^6.0.1",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.3.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  }
```

Comment: In case it might help ‍♂️, full public repo is here ➡️ https://github.com/sebastienbarbier/sebastienbarbier.com/tree/update-dependancies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve such issue, I first slept on it , then generated a brand new angular project using `angular-ci` then adding `@nguniversal/express-engine` to see if I had any major differences.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
npm run prerender
```

Found out my `main.server.ts` file was not correctly initialised. Now works as expected.

### ✅ Correct `main.server.ts` version

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * Initialize the server environment - for example, adding DOM built-in types to the global scope.
 *
 * NOTE:
 * This import must come before any imports (direct or transitive) that rely on DOM built-ins being
 * available, such as `@angular/elements`.
 */
import '@angular/platform-server/init';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server';
export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

### ❌ previous version of `main.server.ts`

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

enableProdMode();

export {AppServerModule} from './app/app.server';
```